# Llamar a una función de una clase base en una derivada

Tags: c++, herencia, polimorfismo

el título no es del todo muy descriptivo, pero os pongo en situación (estoy aprendiendo polimorfismo).

Supongamos que tenemos dos clases:

> Clase base: EmpleadoPorComision
>
> Clase derivada: EmpleadoBaseMasComision

Voy a crear dos objetos de dichas clases y dos punteros que apunten a cada objeto:

```
  EmpleadoPorComision empleadoPorComision("Sue", "Jones", "222-222-2221", 1000, 0.06);
  EmpleadoPorComision *empleadoPorComisionPtr = 0;
  EmpleadoBaseMasComision empleadoBaseMasComision("Bob", "Lewis", "333-332-1122", 5000, 0.04, 300);
  EmpleadoBaseMasComision *empleadoBaseMasComisionPtr = 0;
```

Ahora llamaremos al método "imprimir". Este método pertenece a la clase base, sólo que en la clase derivada, tiene también este método "imprimir" y dentro de él se llama a imprimir de la clase base + función que muestra un atributo de la clase derivada.

Ahora, lo que voy es a usar el método imprimir usando esos punteros:

```
  empleadoPorComisionPtr = &empleadoPorComision;
  empleadoPorComisionPtr->imprimir(); //Invoca a imprimir de la clase base
  empleadoBaseMasComisionPtr = &empleadoBaseMasComision;
  empleadoBaseMasComisionPtr->imprimir(); //Invoca a imprimir de la clase derivada
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es cuando realizo esto:

```
  empleadoPorComisionPtr = &empleadoBaseMasComision;
  empleadoPorComisionPtr->imprimir(); //Invoca a la funcion imprimir de la clase base
```

Este último imprimir() llama a imprimir pero de la clase base. Como veis, en realidad a ese puntero último (empleadoPorComisionPtr) le estoy diciendo que apunte al objeto empleadoBaseMasComision, es decir, a un objeto de la clase derivada, sin embargo, **¿porqué el método imprimir que usa es el de la clase base, y no el de la clase derivada?**

Muchísimas gracias a todos, un saludo.

Edito:

> Definición de las clases:
>
> Definición de la clase base EmpleadoPorComision:

```
class EmpleadoPorComision
{
public:
  EmpleadoPorComision(const string &, const string &, const string &, double=0.0, double=0.0);
  void establecerPrimerNombre(const string&); //Establece el primer nombre
  string conseguirPrimerNombre() const; //Devuelve el primer conseguirPrimerNombre
  void establecerApellidoPaterno(const string&);
  string conseguirApellidoPaterno() const;
  void establecerNumeroSS(const string&);
  string conseguirNumeroSS() const;
  void establecerVentasBrutas(double);
  double conseguirVentasBrutas() const;
  void establecerTarifaComision(double);
  double conseguirTarifaComision() const;

  double ingresos() const;  //Calcula los ingresos
  void imprimir() const;  //Imprime el objeto EmpleadoPorComision
private:
  string primerNombre;
  string apellidoPaterno;
  string numeroSS;
  double ventasBrutas;  //Ventas brutas por semana
  double tarifaComision;  //Porcentaje de comision
};
```

> Definición de la clase derivada EmpleadoBaseMasComision:

```
class EmpleadoBaseMasComision : public EmpleadoPorComision
{
public:
  EmpleadoBaseMasComision(const string&, const string&, const string&, double=0.0, double=0.0, double=0.0);
  void establecerSalarioBase(double);
  double conseguirSalarioBase() const;
  double ingresos() const;
  void imprimir() const;
private:
  //El resto de miembros de datos se heredan de la clase base.
  double salarioBase;
};
```

Comment: Por favor, incluye las definiciones de las clases.

Comment: Error mío, ya he añadido las clases, disculpa @Paula_plus_plus Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para que el polimorfismo funcione en este caso, es decir, que se llame a la función de la clase hija, es necesario que las funciones a sobreescribir estén etiquetadas como virtuales en la clase base:

```
class EmpleadoPorComision
{
    // ...

    virtual void imprimir() const;  //Imprime el objeto EmpleadoPorComision
//  ^^^^^^^  
};
```

Adicionalmente, a partir de C++11, es recomendable marcar las funciones que de las clases derivadas que sobreescriben a una virtual como `override`:

```
class EmpleadoBaseMasComision : public EmpleadoPorComision
{
    // ...

    void imprimir() const override;
    //                    ^^^^^^^^
};
```

De esta forma si la función no va a ser sobreescrita (porque has metido la pata básicamente), el compilador mostrará un mensaje de error:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void func();
  virtual void func2() const;
  void func3();
};

struct Derivada : Base
{
  void func() override; // OK
  void func2() override; // ERROR!!!! falta const
  void func3() override; // ERROR!!!! la funcion base no es virtual
};
```

**¿Por qué no funciona el polimorfismo sin virtual?**

Cuando se llama a una función miembro normal (para entendernos, no virtual), el compilador genera una llamada directa a una función, es decir, en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
struct Base
{
  void func();
};

struct Derivada : Base
{
  void func();
};

Base* base = new Derivada;
base->func();
```

Dado que el puntero es de tipo `base`, el compilador generará una llamada a `Base::func` pese a que existe `Derivada::func`.

¿Por qué?

Básicamente, porque las llamadas no virtuales se calculan en tiempo de compilación y, dado que en tiempo de compilación el compilador únicamente tiene el puntero de tipo `Base`, la función a ejecutar será `Base::func`.

Esto es debido a que la intención de C++ ha sido siempre optimizarlo en beneficio de la velocidad, por lo que se aplican todas las optimizaciones posibles en el código generado.

**¿Y qué pasa si la función es virtual?**

Si declaras la función de la clase base como `virtual` lo que sucede es que durante el proceso de compilación se genera, en la clase base, un puntero a función. Este puntero a función apuntará a la versión que proceda, de tal forma que podremos llamar a funciones de la clase hija desde la clase padre:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void func(); // <<--- Genera un puntero a funcion
};

struct Derivada : Base
{
  void func() override; // <<--- Sobreescribe el puntero a funcion de la clase padre
};

Base* base = new Derivada;
base->func(); // Se realiza la llamada a traves del puntero a funcion
```

Los punteros a función de los que hablo no son visibles. Sin embargo se puede apreciar su efecto en que las llamadas a funciones virtuales son sensiblemente más lentas (en vez de una llamada directa se llama a un puntero a función).

Comment: Buenas @eferion gracias, claro, el libro que estoy siguiendo va explicando poco a poco el polimorfismo, y ese "error" que se comete imagino que es a drede para explicar luego la etiqueta virtual como me comentas. El caso es que aun así, no entiendo porqué aun el puntero apuntando a la clase derivada, no usa imprimir de la clase derivada. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @ProgrammerJr me has pillando editando la pregunta...

Comment: ¡qué habilidad! más o menos y a falta de practicar más ejemplos lo entiendo. Mil gracias compañero.